# How to speed up successive pd.apply with successive pd.DataFrame.loc calls?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization

```
def __link_price(row: pd.Series) -> Union[None, float]:
    if (row['fund'] == 'A') and (row['share_class'] == 'X'):
        return df_hist.loc[row['date'], 'AA']
    elif (row['fund'] == 'A') and (row['share_class'] == 'Y'):
        return df_hist.loc[row['date'], 'AB']
    elif (row['fund'] == 'B') and (row['share_class'] == 'X'):
        return df_hist.loc[row['date'], 'BA']
    elif (row['fund'] == 'B') and (row['share_class'] == 'Y'):
        return df_hist.loc[row['date'], 'BB']
    elif (row['fund'] == 'C') and (row['share_class'] == 'X'):
        return df_hist.loc[row['date'], 'CA']
    elif (row['fund'] == 'C') and (row['share_class'] == 'Y'):
        return df_hist.loc[row['date'], 'CB']
    else:
        return 0

df.loc[:, 'price'] = df.apply(__link_price_at_purchase, axis=1).values
```

`df` has 10,000+ lines, so this code is taking a long time. In addition for each row, I'm doing a `df_hist.loc` call to get the value.

I'm trying to speed up this section of code and then option I've found so far is using:

```
df.loc[:, 'price'] = df.apply(__link_price_at_purchase, axis=1, raw=True).values
```

But this forces me to use index based selection for `row` instead of value selection:

```
if (row[0] == 'A') and (row[1] == 'X')
```

which reduces the readability of the code.

I'm looking for an approach that both speeds up the code and still allows for readability of the code.

Comment: I would chain calls to `np.where`

Comment: Use `np.select` if you've multiple `if/else` conditions otherwise `np.where`.

Comment: That said, what are the formats of these dataframes? Perhaps you could do a `merge_asof` instead

Comment: The problem is the second dataframe column and row selection is conditional on values from the row of the first dataframe, so a merge isn't possible.

Comment: Is the index same as `df['date']`?

Comment: @Cyttorak the index is just numerical. I can set the index to do any joining required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, there is a certain cost for each attribute or item lookup and function call. And you don't have a compiler that optimizes things for you.

Here are some general recommendations:

1. Try creating a column that includes `fund` and `share_class` without using Python functions and then merge it with `df_hist`

```py
# convert history from 'wide' format into 'long' format
hist = df_hist.set_index("date").stack()
prices = (
    # create key column for join
    df.assign(key=df["fund"] + df["share_class"].replace({"X": "A", "Y": "B"}))
    .set_index(["date", "key"])
    .join(hist)  # join by index
)
```

2. If it's not trivial to create a `key` column, minimize attribute lookups inside the apply function:

```py
def __link_price(row):
    date, fund, share_class = row[["date", "fund", "share_class"]]
    
    if fund == 'A' and share_class == 'X':
        return df_hist.loc[date, 'AA']
    ...
```

3. Optimize `if` conditions. For example, you need to check 6 conditions in case where `(row['fund'] == 'C') and (row['share_class'] == 'Y')`. You can reduce this number to ... 1.

```py
fund_and_share_class_to_key = {
    ("A", "X"): "AA",
    ("A", "Y"): "AB",
    ...
}

key = fund_and_share_class_to_key.get((fund, share_class))
return df_hist.loc[date, key] if key is not None else 0
```

4. Pandas itself is pretty slow for non-vectorized and non-arithmetic operations. In your case it's better to use standard python dicts for faster lookups.

```py
# small benchmark
df = pd.DataFrame({"value": [4,5,6]})
d = df.to_dict(orient="index")
%timeit df.loc[1, "value"]  # 8.7ms
%timeit d[1]["value"]       # 50ns; ~170 times faster
```

```
# convert dataframe into the dict with format:
# {<date>: {"AA": <value>}}
history = df_hist.set_index("date").to_dict(orient="index")

def __link_price(row):
    ...
    price = history.get(date, {}).get(key, 0)
    return price
```

5. It should be faster to pass history as an apply argument rather than search it in the non-local scope. It also makes the code cleaner.

```py
def __link_price(row, history):
    ...
df.apply(__link_price, args=(history, ))
```

To summarize, a faster function would be something like this:

```
history = df_hist.set_index("date").to_dict(orient="index")
# we don't need to create a mapping on every __link_price call
fund_and_share_class_to_key = {
    ("A", "X"): "AA",
    ("A", "Y"): "AB",
    ...
}
def __link_price(row, history, fund_and_share_class_to_key):
    date, fund, share_class = row[["date", "fund", "share_class"]]
    key = fund_and_share_class_to_key.get((fund, share_class))
    return history.get(date, {}).get(key, 0)

df.apply(__link_price, args=(history, fund_and_share_class_to_key))
```